# I think I found a general formula for the square root of imaginary numbers. Is this correct?

Tags: complex-numbers, solution-verification, radicals

I believe I found a formula for finding the square roots of any imaginary number. The formula is as follows:
$\pm \sqrt{ai} = \pm \sqrt{\frac{a}{2}}i \pm \sqrt{\frac{a}{2}}$

and here is my proof:

$\pm \sqrt{ai} = \pm \sqrt{\frac{a}{2}}i \pm \sqrt{\frac{a}{2}} \\
\pm ai = (\pm \sqrt{\frac{a}{2}}i \pm \sqrt{\frac{a}{2}})^2 \\
\pm ai = (\pm \sqrt{\frac{a}{2}}i)^2 \pm 2\sqrt{\frac{a}{2}}\sqrt{\frac{a}{2}}i + \sqrt{\pm \frac{a}{2}}^2 \\
\pm ai = \mp \frac{a}{2} \pm 2 \times \frac{a}{2}i \pm \frac{a}{2} \\
\pm ai = \pm \frac{2a}{2}i \\
\pm ai = \pm ai$

Is this correct? if so, has it been discovered prior to my finding? I can't find it anywhere on google.

Comment: How familiar are you with the geometry of complex multiplication in the complex plane?

Comment: @Arthur Not much, I was just playing around with square roots of complex and imaginary numbers and found a pattern.

Comment: If you know the geometric interpretation of complex multiplication, and thus complex squaring, and thus complex square rooting, the pattern is much more obvious than with pure algebra and symbols. Still, good on you for finding it. Discovering things on your own is cool, regardless of whether you're the first one to do it.

Comment: So to answer the question about whether it is known, yes it is a known result. They will write it as 

$$cos(\theta) + i sin(\theta) = e^{i\theta}$$.

So,

$$i  = e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}}$$

and

$$\sqrt{i}  = e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}} = cos(\frac{\pi}{4}) + isin(\frac{\pi}{4}) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(1+i)$$

Comment: Yeah. Most of the results we find won't be new, but it shouldn't get you down, especially in the early days of study. It is all part of learning. Self discovery is the best path to learning in some ways.

Comment: @openproblem Ok. That trig hurts my brain so I'm gonna let that sink in, but also thank you. To be honest, I believe that my formula would be a bit more digestible than $\cos(\theta) + i \sin(\theta) = e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}}$ but thank you for clarifying. Also, thank you Arthur as well. You two were a great help.

Comment: @EricTowers I just forgot the $\pm$ lol. I'll edit that now.

Comment: Next step: find a formula for $\sqrt{a+bi}$ (with $a,b$ real).

Comment: @GerryMyerson been trying to get at that for a while xD. I know that both parts are dependent on both variables so now I try

Comment: Nice work, even though not new. Your proof would be much better without any plus/minus signs and square root signs, except for the $\sqrt{a/2}$. Just write the two candidates for the square root and square them to show that they work.

Comment: I was once very excited to have discovered the Stern-Brocot tree (calculating the fraction of time I'd got left to do by counting the number of days before I was released). Thought I'd discovered a wonderful and new thing. Years later shared it with my Number Theory tutor. She hadn't heard of it. I delightedly thought I'd invented a new thing till I got hold of Concrete Maths by Knuth, Graham and Patashnik. Didn't stop my enthusiasm to look for new stuff.